# Flexbox doesn't wrap inside a grid element

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm currently teaching myself grid and flex.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  I want the items in the flexbox to wrap around inside the single grid-content  and make this element grow to fit all the flex box items inside it.

I have a css grid to set up my basic layout, but I want the (single) grid content cell to then have a flexbox as its content, so that a series of content items will then wrap around inside this single grid item.

My html looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="general.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid-2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexbox.css">
        
        <title>Grid and flex</title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="grid_container">
            <div class="grid-item grid-header">header</div>
            <div class="grid-item grid-sidebar">sidebar</div>
            <div class="grid-item grid-content flex-container">item 1
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 1</div>                
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 2</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 3</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 4</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 5</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 6</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 7</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 8</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 9</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 10</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 11</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 12</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 13</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 14</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 15</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 16</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 17</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 18</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 19</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 20</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 21</div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-content">item 22</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item grid-footer">footer</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My grid-2.css looks like this:
/* grid css*/

```
.grid_container {
    display: grid;
    /* margin: 1em; */
    /* padding: 1em; */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    width: 300px;
}
.grid-item {
    background-color: steelblue;
    color: white;
    border: skyblue 1px solid;
}

.grid-sidebar {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 8;
}

.grid-header {
    grid-column: 1/6;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.grid-footer {
    grid-column: 1/6;
}

.grid-content {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    width: 50em;
}
```

and my flexbox.css looks like this:

```
/* flexbox css */

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
    width: 10em;

}

.flex-content {
    border-radius: 1em; /* use this to give a nice rounded border to our items */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    font-size: 1.5em; 
    justify-content: center; /* main axis alignment */
    align-items: center; /* cross axis alignment */
    align-content: flex-start;
    gap: 2em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;

}
```

But, instead of wrapping, the flexbox items, seem to just disappear off the side of the element thus:

[image: resulting html display]

Comment: You forgot to add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to your flex-container. It applies to the parent not the child as you have it now.

Comment: yep - that's it - Thanks heaps @Paulie_D

Comment: Note that it's probably an antipattern to use flex inside a grid cell like this. Nesting different layouts like that is almost always a pain and can usually be avoided.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip @ChristianLegge